# Нужен совет по использованию параметров конфигурации взятых из ENV VAR

Tags: golang

Пишу небольшой микросервис задача которого делать аутентификацию и выдавать JWT токены. В одной из функции используется секрет, который на данный момент просто объявлен как глобальная константа.
Хочется вынести его как часть конфига и передавать в виде environment variable.

Пока я представляю что инициализацию конфига (в т.ч. и других вещей) правильно делать в main. Но получается что функция где требуется секрет, закопана глубоко в код. Условно говоря это код относящийся к http хэндлеру и соответственно чтобы мне донести до туда секрет, мне нужно эту переменную прокинуть через несколько функций в виде аргумента. Что выглядит не совсем элегантно.

С другой стороны я понимаю что секрет лежит в env vars и я могу в любом месте программы сделать os.Getenv('MYSECRET') и прочитать секрет из переменной, но этот способ мне кажется неявным и в будущем может добавить неочевидности к вопросу откуда берется секрет.

Думаю что проблема не нова и у нее есть какое-то простое решение.

P.S. Понимаю что вопрос довольно общий, поэтому был бы рад услышать разные соображения и кто как делает у себя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единого ответа тут нет, каждый делает как хочет. Так как вопрос очень общий, я выскажу своё мнение,
а если у кого-то есть другое, пускай пишут своё.

Каждый пакет должен быть самодостаточен, а вся конфигурация должна быть явной и локальной, и никогда
не должна быть глобальной. То есть, если у вас есть, каждый пакет должен определять свой конфиг. А в
main'е вы собираете из этих почти независимых компонентов нужный функционал. Например:

```golang
package foo

// Config is the Foo configuration structure.
type Config {
  // ...
}

// New returns a new Foo if c is valid.
func New(c *Config) (f Foo, err error) {
  // ...
}
```

```golang
package bar

// Config is the Bar configuration structure.
type Config {
  // ...
}

// New returns a new Bar if c is valid.
func New(c *Config) (b Bar, err error) {
  // ...
}
```

```golang
package main

// ...

func main() {
  var secret = os.Getenv("MYSECRET")
  // ...
  var fc = &foo.Config{
    Secret: secret,
  }

  var f, err = foo.New(fc)
  // ...

  var bc = &bar.Config{
    Foo: foo,
  }

  var b, err = bar.New(bc)
  // ...
}
```

Некоторые засовывают конфигурацию в один глобальный объект и используют его во всём проекте, но
из-за этого становится малопонятно, что где используется, не говоря уже о том, что это глобальное
изменяемое состояние. А уж проблем с порядком инициализации сколько. В общем, не рекомендую
глобальную конфигурацию.

Comment: Да, именно, я во многом согласен с вами про самодостаточность модулей и явность сущностей, при этом хочется избежать глобальной "помойки" для конфигурации. Ваш вариант мне нравится и он хорошо укладывается на то как сейчас организован код.